# what does 'hasattr(object, name)' mean in this code?

Tags: python

I am reading a sourse code and get some doubt.Here is the code:

```
class EventLoop(object):
def __init__(self):
    if hasattr(select, 'epoll'):
        self._impl = select.epoll(hasattr(object, name))
        model = 'epoll'
    elif hasattr(select, 'kqueue'):
        self._impl = KqueueLoop()
        model = 'kqueue'
    elif hasattr(select, 'select'):
        self._impl = SelectLoop()
        model = 'select'
    else:
        raise Exception('can not find any available functions in select '
                        'package')
```

Referenced to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html),the method is 'select.epoll([sizehint=-1])'.But in this case,what does 'hasattr(object, name)' mean in this code ?I can't find the declartion of the variable 'name'.

Comment: `hasattr(object, name)` returns `True` if the `object` has an attribute `name` and `False` if it doesn't. [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr)

Answer (score 1):

[`hasattr(object,name)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) in python checks if some object has an attribute with name `name`.

In this case it checks if module `select` has one of the attributes (functions are attributes too) listed in the documentation.

This is done in order to find the best I/O completion implementation available on this platform.

Not all functions from the module are available at the same time and therefore might not be present in the module (see [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)):

- `epoll` - as per doc `Only supported on Linux 2.5.44 and newer`
- `poll` - as per doc `Not supported by all operating systems`
- `kqueue` - as per doc `Only supported on BSD`
- `select` - should be available everywhere.

E.g. if `epoll` is available it is given a preference, if `epoll` is not available `poll` is tried, then `kqueue` and, finally, `select`.

When even `select` is not available `Exception` is thrown.

Adding a concrete example of `hasattr`.

- Verb: `hasattr`
- Where: `object` to look into
- What: `name` of the attribute (e.g a string)

.

```
# attribute of object of type string
obj = "some string"
print(hasattr(obj, 'find')) # True
print(hasattr(obj, 'nonexistentattr')) # False

# attribute of a module `math`
import math
# Check directly
print(hasattr(math, 'cos')) # True
# ...or check via variable
obj = math # obj is now a module
print(hasattr(obj, 'cos')) # True
```

Comment: what does 'name' mean?I can't find the declartion of the variable 'name'.

Comment: `name` is the second argument to function `hasattr`. first arg is "where", second is "what". so `name` is what are you looking for among the object's attributes.